# Javascript mapping of new Array()

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

`new Array(3)`returns an array of length 3 containing 3 `undefined`s which is equivalent to `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`;

However,

`[undefined, undefined, undefined].map((val, i) => i)` produces the expected result of `[0, 1, 2]`. But `new Array(3).map((val, i) => i)` produces `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`, as if the map function had not effect whatsoever.

Could anyone explain why?

EDIT
Looks like there is a flaw in my understanding of `new Array()`. It does NOT create a new array. It creates an object with key `length` equal to the argument passed in. Thanks for the answers and comments.

Btw if you do need an array like `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` to iterate/map over, or for anything then `[...new Array(m)]` should do the trick.

Comment: *containing 3 undefineds which is equivalent to [undefined, undefined, undefined];* That's wrong.

Comment: Arrays in Javascript are exotic objects with numeric properties and a `length` property.
In the case of `new Array(3)`, you generate an `Array` object with its `length` set to 3, but none of the numeric properties.  You can see this:

    > Object.keys( new Array( 3 ) );
    []

    > Object.keys( [ undefined, undefined, undefined] );
    ["0", "1", "2"]

You can achieve what you want with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=control):

    > Object.keys( Array.from( { length: 3 } ) );
    ["0", "1", "2"]

Comment: Doh.  Locked before I could post my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An important thing to understand that there is no array type in javascript. Built-in `Array` is just a convenience wrapped over the standard `Object`. The only difference is that Arrays have the `length` property, computed in a special way.

`new Array(3)` returns an object with a single `length` field. It doesn't contain any other keys.

```
{
   length: 3
}
```

`[undefined, undefined, undefined]` creates an object with 3 numeric slots:

```
{
   length: 3
   0: undefined,
   1: undefined,
   2: undefined,
}
```

That makes difference, because `map` and other iterators look for numeric keys that actually exist in the object. The logic behind `map`, `forEach` and friends is like this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
      if (A.hasOwnProperty(i))
          do something with A[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

> new Array(3)returns an array of length 3 containing 3 undefineds which is equivalent to [undefined, undefined, undefined];

Not according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

> this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values

Answer (score 3):

when you do new Array(3) Javascript reserves memory for an Array of 3 elements, but does not define any of them.

When you do create an array via [undefined, undefined undefined] it actually creates 3 elements which value is undefined each of them (therefore, it is an array of length 3).